# in memory (main memory) database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, memory-optimized-tables

I have an internship and they gave me a project about ms sql in memory database.End of the internship, we loaded database lots of data.

My task is to take any file in minimum time.I researched the topic on the internet especially on microsoft site.But there is no implementation part on the internet.How can I do this task.Can anyone help me?I cannnot understand actually what I need to do?

Actually I understand the concept of in memory database.Microsoft added a new feature into system which is called Hekaton.It increases the speed.

The company asked me that How can we use this feature implementing into our system which can be integrated with erp programs.

They will load into db lots of things.I need to get anything from db while using the in-memory database.How? Where I need to start to implement this?

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hekaton is a solution for very specific problems, so I wouldn't just say "It increases the speed". To make sure your project has a chance to succeed, you should really spend time on understanding what Hekaton is and what problems it can solve. There's plenty of videos available for example in Channel 9, SQLPass.org and Youtube.

If the problem really is just the implementation, there are also [code samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133079.aspx) available.

Answer (score 0):

[MS SQL In-Memory OLTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186(v=sql.120).aspx)

[MS SQL In-Memory OLTP – Common Workload Patterns and Migration Considerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn673538.aspx)